# Triggering an email from a new list entry in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, triggered-send

Does anyone have any idea about a way to trigger an email when a subscriber is added to a list in Marketing Cloud?

A 3rd party is sending us subscribers but their standard integration creates list entries rather than Data Extension ones.

The only way I can think of is with an automated SQL query from the list to a DE but that can only be scheduled on the hour. I'd like the send to be immediate.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario - I would use a welcome email option provided in the list creation option.

Basically while setting up a new list you can choose to send a welcome email and any email can be selected to use as part of the welcome email.

As a result you will get the external key of the list which can be used in the triggered send definition and it will work similar to triggered send DE definition. Every time a new record is pushed to the list via triggered send def, the email will be sent to that respective email address.

[image]